# Remote Control/Shadow mutilpe users on Server 2008 R2 Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to remote control / shadow more than one user on Server 2008 R2?

In our organisation we have a quite a few people who work from home and are located across the country.  They all log onto our server using Remote Desktop and they work on the server.  The team supervisor is currently having to shadow each user individualy when they have a query / problem. Is there a way we can shado more than 1 person at a time so that we can quickly fix/answer small querys whilst tackling bigger issues?

If its not something that can be done natively in Server 2008 R2 is there a 3rd party option to allow this?

Answer (score 1):

Even if there are 3rd party applications aimed for this specific thing, I don't see how having multiple shadowing sessions will help you (or your team supervisor) handle support issues 'better/faster'.  In my opinion, as part of good remote support etiquette, whenever I need to troubleshoot a session remotely, I need to contact the individual am about to shadow, and make sure she/he is ready for the support/troubleshooting prior to connecting.  This would be the first issue as I'd need to have as many people on the line as I'm about to control remotely.

Back to the question at hand though, I don't think there is a way to do it natively through RDP.  You could VNC to many machines, but it gets trickier if they are in remote locations (might needs something like **[this](https://serverfault.com/questions/100229/inexpensive-remote-assistance-software/100244#100244)**, or a combo of solutions just to get this functionality).

Comment: Agreed. I don't see how having the ability to shadow multiple users increases the effectiveness or expediency of the support. You have to attend to one user at a time.